# Использование нескольких паттернов для форматирования даты для одного поля

Tags: java, json, spring, elasticsearch

В настоящее время в проекте используется Elasticsearch и Spring Boot 1.5.6.
В классе, который помечен как @Document существует поле типа ZonedDateTime.
Проблема заключается в том, что для корректного распознавания данного поля Elasticsearch необходимо использовать паттерн для распарсивания даты, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed,
        format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", locale = "ENGLISH")
private ZonedDateTime displayDate;
```

Все указанное необходимо для того, чтобы корректно работал Elasticsearch (мог проиндексировать дату), при этом он использует fasterxml.
Вместе с тем существует контроллер (используется Spring WEB), который возвращает экземпляр класса, содержащего указанную дату, в ResponseEntity. 
Spring WEB также использует fasterxml, однако для ResponseEntity поле с датой должно иметь другой формат вида "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a".

Вопрос состоит в том, чтобы задать 2  формата даты для fasterxml, один из которых будет использовать Elasticsearch , а второй Spring WEB.

Хочется найти красивое решение.
Интересны любые предложения.
Спасибо.